# Missing asp.net web application template in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I installed Visual Studio 2010 (ultimate).

When I click on New Project-> Visual Basic (or C#)-> Web, the only options i get is AjaxControlExtender, AjaxServerControl and ASP.Net Server Control. How do i get the ASP.Net WebApplication option to show up?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

What you need to do is re-run the installation (should be maintenance mode), and add Visual Web Developer. That probably isn't installed, which is why you wouldn't see any web templates but the ajaxcontrolextener templates. If you see that it is installed they try running devenv.exe with the /installvstemplates (i.e. "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"  /installvstemplates).

Hope that helps!