# Visual Studio 2010 missing ASP.NET projects templates?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

So brand new installation of .NET Framework 4.0 and Visual Studio 2010 on a brand new computer. Loading up Visual Studio 2010 and selecting New Project only lists the following project typess under "Web":

ASP.NET MVC 3 Web App
AjaxControlExtender
AjaxServerControl
ASP.NET Server Control

All of the other project types are missing and I can't load existing .NET projects (gives me the "project type not supported" error. Any idea what happened or how I can reinstall the missing templates?

I've already tried running devenv.exe /installvstemplates with elevated privileges.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042408/missing-asp-net-web-application-template-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373899/project-template-missing-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345498/asp-net-web-service-application-missing-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: Are you sure you told the installer to install the Visual Web Developer component?

Comment: I'll try installing the VWD component...

Comment: That did it...No one suggested it in the context of an answer though. Can't accept comments!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you didn't install the Visual Web Developer component, the ASP.NET project templates won't be fully installed. Naturally, because the installer then thinks it doesn't need to put them there as ASP.NET is a web development framework.

In that case, just run the installer again and make sure Visual Web Developer is checked. The installer will then add the appropriate project templates.

Answer (score 2):

[Default Project Templates in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fyc0azh.aspx)

> Available templates may vary according to Visual Studio version, SKU,
>   installation options, and other customizations. If you are missing a
>   template that comes with your installation, ***run devenv.exe with the
>   /installvstemplates switch***. For more information, see [How to:
>   Restore Default Project Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247116.aspx).