# In vs2010, I am not able to see any templates like empty asp .net website

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When i open vs2010 then click on create new website , I am not able to see any templates like empty asp .net website, it shows no templates, How can I get back all templates , help me , thanks in advance ?

Comment: Can you try running "msdev /installvstemplates" from a command prompt? You may need elevated privileges.

Comment: its not working....pls tel another solution ??

Comment: Try "devenv /installvstemplates" instead?

Answer (score 0):

Taken completely from [Mitch Wheat's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16076/mitch-wheat) answer on  [Visual Studio 2010 missing ASP.NET projects templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887270/visual-studio-2010-missing-asp-net-projects-templates/6887281#6887281)

> [Default Project Templates in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fyc0azh.aspx)
>
> > Available templates may vary according to Visual Studio version, SKU,
> >     installation options, and other customizations. If you are missing a
> >     template that comes with your installation, ***run devenv.exe with the
> >     /installvstemplates switch***. For more information, see [How to:
> >     Restore Default Project Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247116.aspx).

Comment: how to rundevenv.exe with the /installvstemplates switch .hope u dnt mind for that . thnks in advance .i need your help

Comment: Open a command prompt as administrator then just type the command. If you follow the Default Project Templates link it will tell you how.

Comment: its not working bro ... help me out pls

Comment: In what way is it not working, I'll need more information than that to have a chance of helping you :)

Comment: i hav reinstalld vs2010 ...now its working fine...anyways thnks for ur help :)