# Visual Studio 2013 - No Visual Basic/Visual C# Web Templates Installed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I've installed Visual Studio 2013 Premium (MSDN license) on my machine. Yet, the ASP.NET Web Application template is not there (except for Version2012, which offers me MVC 4, see screenshot below):

[image: Image showing no web templates available]

I have uninstalled and reinstalled VS2013 three times now. I've deleted the ItemTemplatesCache and ProjectTemplatesCache folders along with running the devenv /InstallVSTemplates and devenv /Setup to no avail. I've also checked to make sure web developer tools are installed. Under the \Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplatesCache\CSharp\Web folder, I only see MVC 4 template files. Am I missing something? An extension or additional program?

Below I added a screenshot of the frameworks I have installed. Any direction or advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

[image: Image showing frameworks installed]

Jodie.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing asp.net web application template in Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042408/missing-asp-net-web-application-template-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: Hi nrathaus. Sadly the solution you posted doesn't work. I ran the log file and found errors and warnings but nothing specific to the web project template.

I also took a look into these registry keys and found they are pointing at the right folders:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\VSTemplate\Project;
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\VSTemplate\Item;
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VSTemplate\Item;
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VSTemplate\Project;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many hours of troubleshooting, these are the steps I took to fix the issue (on Windows 7 Ultimate). I assumed it was an issue with a corrupt installation and possible problems with registry keys, so I removed any and all Microsoft development tools using the following steps:

- FULL VIRUS SCAN (just to make sure this was not related to a virus or malware). I used Microsoft Security Essentials
- Downloaded [Microsoft FixIt](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall/) to help clean up registry keys as I deleted programs. After I deleted any program or program updates, I ran this tool to verify a clean uninstall had been done
- Visual Studio 2010 - Ran the [Visual Studio 2010 Uninstall Utility](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vs2010uninstall) and removed the program. Went into Control Panel > Programs > Uninstall a program > View Installed Updates and searched for 'Visual Studio 2010', then removed any updates associated with VS2010 (and ran the FixIt program after every uninstall to verify the registry keys had been wiped)
- Followed [this MSDN post](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2771441/en-us) to remove Visual Studio 2012 (paying particular attention to the 'Optional Shared Packages' and removed any and all programs under this list, again running Microsoft FixIt to verify the registry keys were wiped)
- Followed [this blog post from Shawn Harrison](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/ShawnHarrison/ssis/2156/how-to-uninstall-sql-server) to remove all SQL server; also referenced these two MSDN posts [Uninstall an Existing Instance of SQL Server (Setup)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143412.aspx) and [SQL Server Files Left After Uninstall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882462.aspx)
- Uninstalled Visual Studio 2013, along with all references to 'Visual Studio 2013' in programs and installed updates; used FixIt to clean up registry keys after every install
- Last but not least, I removed all MVC Visual Studio-related tools, references extensions including Web Tools and Web Platform Installer

This solved my problem with missing templates :)

(I'm soooooooo grateful this was all done on an SSD, however, I think it would have taken 5x longer with an old-spinning HD)

Cheers, everyone!

Answer (score 16):

I think that "Re-install Visual Studio from scratch" is not a solution.

I have faced with the described problem and found much faster way to fix it:

1. First of all, try to repair Visual Studio installation (in **"Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features"** find your Visual Studio, right-click and select **"Repair"**). Reboot after (!).
2. Check if template appeared in the Visual Studio. If not, then: in the **"Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features"** make sure that you have **"Microsoft Web Platform Installer 4.x"** installed (I have 4.6 version). If not - install it from here: http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx
3. Run **"Web Platform Installer"** (it should be here: **"%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\WebPlatformInstaller.exe"**)
4. On the "Products" tab find the line **"Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2013"** (make sure that it is not for 2012!). If line has "Add" button on the right side enabled, then click it and install the tools. Reboot PC (!) and you should have your ASP.NET project template back.
5. If line says "Installed", then you should repair it via **"Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features"**, just find **"Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 -Visual Studio 2013"**, right-click and select **"Repair"**). Reboot PC (!) and you should have your ASP.NET project template back!

Cheers!

Comment: I didn't find that on line 4 ("Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2013") but selecting Visual Studio 2013 for Azure 2.3 (even though I had VS 2013 Express installed) added the Web stuff also.

Comment: Along with Valentin, I didn't find that item in the Web Platform Installer. A little digging revealed that package was bundled with VS 2013 Update 2 (and later 3). In lieu of steps 3-5, I'd recommend repairing VS 2013 Update 3, which can be done here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43721 (Just click download, and, assuming you have it installed, it'll give you the option to repair your install). Finally, in my case, I suspect I got into this situation by having multiple versions of VS installed when I installed VS2013 and its Update 3.

Comment: Step 5 working for me, because tool is already installed on my machine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Not the solution in your case, but I had a similar issue where I could not find the MVC templates. Eventually I realized that I still had .NET Framework 3.5 selected, which of course does not provide MVC... switching to .NET Framework 4.5 let me find the MVC templates again.

You already had 4.5 selected in the screenshot, but I'm just posting this here for others who might make the same mistake as I did.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to check that "Microsoft Web Developer Tool" was actually enabled during installation see this related stackoverflow question: [How do I open a csproj with ProjectTypeGuids 349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636034/how-to-open-a-csproj-with-projecttypeguids-349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21)
"Microsoft Web Developer Tool" that was the problem for me

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried updating the gallery
Tools>Extension and updates> Templates

To get up and running you could click Version 2012 under Web and get to the stock web applications templates which will provide you upto MVC 4
For MVC 5 you can either download Visual Studio 2013 Express Web, it roughly has the same ASP.NET features at Premium on MSDN License.

Comment: I will do this as a last resort. I'm thinking at this point I need an uninstall utility to clean this all up.

Answer (score 0):

Update for Studio 2013:
Make sure you install express for Windows and not express for Windows Desktop.  The Desktop version does not have the Web templates.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with VS 2013 Web Express Update 3. After reinstalling stuff all week its fixed. I had to uninstall VS, delete the "Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0" directory, and reinstall VS. There are other [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25270008/cant-create-new-mvc5-project-or-any-other-asp-net-projects-in-visual-studio-20/25276352#25276352) that are more precise.

Comment: please don't link to answers which received downvotes. also, you linked to an answer which is already similar to your answer here.