# MVC 4 project template missing from Visual Studio 2013 project templates list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

Does anyone know why the MVC 4 Project Template hass disappeared !from my 2012 Project Template list in Visual Studio 2013. It appeared until recently when i added the SQL Data Tools to my Visual Studio 2013 installation and since then it is not appearing. Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

[Current Project Template View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeuTn.png)

Thanks, Phil.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2013 - No Visual Basic/Visual C# Web Templates Installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823499/visual-studio-2013-no-visual-basic-visual-c-sharp-web-templates-installed)