# Visual studio 2013, can't create projects

Tags: visual-studio

I had visual studio 2013 installed on my laptop and I could create projects a few months back, today I tried to create a project, **FILE -> NEW -> PROJECT** the new project window pops up but can't select anything (see screen shot below). After trying a few things I decided to uninstall it and cleaned my machine with CCleaner. I installed a new install again and still the same problem. can someone help and tell me what I need to do.

[image: New Project Pop up window]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2013 - No Visual Basic/Visual C# Web Templates Installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823499/visual-studio-2013-no-visual-basic-visual-c-sharp-web-templates-installed)

Comment: This one might help too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823499/visual-studio-2013-no-visual-basic-visual-c-sharp-web-templates-installed