# Visual Studio 2013 Web Application template empty

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

Probably a really stupid question but, I just installed Visual Studio 2013 and when I try to create a web application the following window is all blank, normally it has MVC, WebAPI, Empty etc but there doesn't seem to be anything here?

[image]

Comment: I think you should reinstall vs 2013. [Here is a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823499/visual-studio-2013-no-visual-basic-visual-c-sharp-web-templates-installed)

Answer (score 0):

Select templates from the new project window. If you want to create application using c#, select c# from the sub menu. There is another sub menu named web there. Click on it. Then you can select ASP.NET web application project template. Click OK button. Then you will be asked for project type and you can select the required project type.

[image: Creating new web application]

[image: Selecting project type]

Comment: Well that is my problem, your second screenshot is what normally comes up but if you look at my screenshot it is all empty, any idea why?

Comment: I think it is an issue because of the corrupt installation. Check this link for a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823499/visual-studio-2013-no-visual-basic-visual-c-sharp-web-templates-installed